# Is it possible to take a video screenshot (screenshow?) of what's occurring on a Macbook Pro's screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, video, screen-capture

I've got an unusual situation which I cannot explain. I thought to take a video of what I'm seeing on the screen, but realized I didn't know how to do that.

Is there a way to take a video of the screen's activities? From terminal, shortcut keys, or another method?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **QuickTime Player.app** for this. Open it and in `File` menu there's `New Screen Recording` or press <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.